# Deleting text of a certain color and the white space before and after - Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I delete the text of a certain color and the white space before and after this text in Microsoft Word? I know only how delete text of a certain color:

- Select Edit | Replace.
- Leave both the 'Find what' and 'Replace with' boxes blank.
- Click More.
- Make sure the 'Find what' box is active, then click the Format dropdown and select Font...
- Select the color for which you want to remove all text.
- Click 'Replace All'.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do a 2 stage find and replace, given that your white space may not have red font colour applied?

First, do your find and replace for red font but instead of replacing with nothing, replace it with text that doesn't appear anywhere else in your document eg "~~~~~~".

Then do a second find and replace, this time with no formatting for colour added.  The find would be "^w~~~~~~^w" (which is white space followed by your placeholder text followed by white space) and replace that with nothing.  (If your text might not always have white space on both sides, you may need to do a couple of extra find and replaces with just a single ^w at either end of your string).